# How to dynamically load C++ function

Tags: c++, function, dynamic, load

I have an C++ application, how can i load function from `test.cpp` function and execute it? I need a solution for Windows and Linux. I need this because my application users should change this function for their needs.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean calling it without compiling it?

Comment: Or, do you mean loading it from a shared object (like a `dll`)?

Comment: @Nick, yes, i need to start function without compiling in application

Comment: You could compile it to a shared library and link that on the fly but this introduces some near insurmountable security issues.

Comment: If python is an option look into http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/

Comment: Well a *.cpp file is not executable. So it either needs to be compiled or run through an interpreter. Though there are interpreters for C++ that would not be my first choice. So what I think you mean is that you have your application `myapp1` that you don't want to modify and you would like to organize it so that you can compile client code into a shared library (or the client can provide the shared library) so that your application would then load it dynamically and execute a specific function in the library. Would this be a better summary.

Answer (score 0):

This is nearly impossible in pure c++. This is because you must compile your function first. When you have an object, ou can dynamically link it into you program, but this is not what you intend to do, i expect.

You might want to look at scripting languages like LUA etc that have well documented API's to be used in c++ (among others)

You can also deliver gcc with you application and call it from the application itself (exec..()) But this is quite heavy.

Comment: This is indeed possible, but is probably not worth the hassle.

Comment: He could also look into C and C++ interpreters (there are a few).

Comment: Probably should not use such forceful words like "Not possible". Nearly anything is possible if you have the determination.

Comment: True, but they are pretty heavy.

Comment: @LokiAstari you are right. If mr. Kerningham and mr. Ritchie had shown the attitude i just showed, we all wouldn't be here.

Comment: @dmaij: If you had been thinking you would have tried to get a clarification of the question and then put on the correct course to solving the the actual problem (rather than the perceived problem). I suspect the actual problem is trivially solved.

Comment: @LokiAstari, if I would have tried to get a clarification, i would have commented the question. If I wanted to solve the question, I would have posted a solution. It's up to you to determine what I did.

Answer (score 0):

make this function in a shared library "dll or so"linux" " and then you can call it dynamically either using "extern " and library (.lib) or 'LibraryLoad (Windows) or dlopen (linux)" .. this is the way to do in c++ .. but you have to make your function call understood static from your program ..

Comment: And you must have a compiler on your customers system.

Comment: it depends on how are you going to deliver the library .. if it is you whom develop it, or a third party, then you can send it to them all they have to do is set the paths, another way is that they send you the code and you compile it - if possible-, or if this is not possible then just give them the compiler directives , library paths and function structure ..

Comment: and that's it they have to compile the code and put the library in the specific path... however you might invoke a compiler in your code so that they might just put a c++ code, this can be done in windows and linux, but much easier in linux , but I don't think this is a good idea unless you deliver your package with the compiler in it (windows specifically and make sure the client have gcc if linux), but yet again this is a poor security design .. the other way is you deliver a script (bat file in windows)

Comment: or whatever script in linux that compile their code and generate a dynamic library and store it in the right path or sets the path on some configuration file

Comment: I agree with you when you are under Linux, since should always be at least a compiler. But windows does not, and this is one of the problems that the author states.

Comment: as I said in windows you can deliver the compiler in the package cl.exe and its dependencies but I don't think this is a good idea ... who down voted this